# User <cword> inside a vimgrep regex expression

Tags: vimrc, regular-expression, vimgrep

Writing a map to find header under cursor for markdown link.

```
## heading {#foo}
...
...
[click on link](#foo) <- `cursur above this foo`
```

What I am doing:

```
nnoremap gO :lvimgrep "\v^#+.*(#.*)" %<CR>:lopen<CR>
```

What I am looking for:

```
nnoremap gO :lvimgrep "\v^#+.*(#<cword>)" %<CR>:lopen<CR>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot missing there. Ignoring the part after the first `<CR>` for now...

First, there are some contexts, i.e. where a filename is expected, where you can use `<cword>` bare. But in many cases, including this one, you need to force it to be resolved or "expanded". That can be done with, naturally, `expand('<cword>')`. Unfortunately, you can't just stick this in between your delimiters (`"`)...`:lvimgrep` only accepts a clean, static string there.

The standard way to deal with dynamic/variable components on the command line is to make a string out of the command and pass it to `:exec`.

Within the string divide things into static and dynamic parts and concatenate them together. Separating into static/dynamic/delimiter parts:

1. `lvimgrep`
2. delimiter
3. `\v^#+.*(`
4. `expand('<cword>')`
5. `)`
6. delimeter
7. `%`

Note that I removed `#` from #3 because it's going to be picked up by `<cword>`.

Now we use single quotes around the static parts to avoid any extra evaluation/interpretation that double quotes may cause. This is just the pattern part (#3-5):

```
'\v^#+.*(' . expand('<cword>') . ')'
```

Bringing in the rest including delimiters (I'm using `/` to avoid complications of quotes) and passing to `:exec`...

```
nnoremap gO :exec 'lvimgrep /\v^#+.*(' . expand('<cword>') . ')/ %'
```

Now you need the second command. That has to be separated from the preceding part with `|` and in mappings that must be escaped as `\|` or `<bar>`...

```
nnoremap gO :exec 'lvimgrep /\v^#+.*(' . expand('<cword>') . ')/ %' \| :lopen<CR>
```

Note that the first `<CR>` you had was unnecessary as the `|` takes care of submitting both commands.

FYI, I tested this and, if I'm understanding your use case correctly, it worked fine.

Comment: I guess it worked for you. :) Given how complicated this is I was sure there'd be a snag or two. Glad there isn't.

Comment: In a single post you cleared many doubts I had. Thanks.
It worked perfectly :)

Comment: Nice! You're welcome.